# Validate cases on MessageBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Message box like this:

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Message", "System message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
 {
 }
```

Now I want to add other cases with "Yes" and "Cancel" because is `MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel` so I try like:

```
 if (MessageBox.Show("Message", "System message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.No)
 {
 }
 else if (DialogResult.Yes)
 {
     return;
 }
 else if (DialogResult.Cancel)
 {
     return;
 }
```

But VisualStudio mark in red and throws:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult' to
>   'bool'

How should I add Yes and Cancel cases in validation?

Comment: store the result in a variable and use that to compare in you if/else block otherwise you risk calling it 2 or 3 times

Comment: High odds that you'll like the [switch statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/switch).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to store the result in a variable of type `DialogResult` :

```
var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Message", "System message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
{
}
else if (dialogResult  == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    return;
}
else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
   return;
}
```

it can be even more better to write like:

```
var dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Message", "System message",
                                   MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
if (dialogResult  == DialogResult.Yes || dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    return;
}

// logic for No here
// as this means No was pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you should store the result of `MessageBox.Show()` into a variable and then use `if` or `switch` to compare the result against one value in `DialogResult`enumeration.

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Message", "System message", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);

if (result == DialogResult.Yes) {
    // do something for yes
} 
else if (result == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
   // do something for cancel
}
else
{
    // this will be no
}
```